# How can insert data into user_level whenever new user register under referral link id

Tags: database, laravel

I create user registeration system with referral link .I want new users to count as level 1 , level 2 users lists and want to credit to sponsor user. I mean if new user register under referral link of user A,he will get referral bonus as amazon. So need to count users in level 1 and level 2. I will only pay for this two level. So I need to insert data whenever new user register as what level of sponsor user. and need to credit to sponsor user.

I have table as this

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id');
       $table->string('name');
       $table->string('email')->unique();
       $table->integer('user_level')->nullable();
       $table->string('referred_by')->nullable();
       $table->string('affiliate_id')->unique();
       $table->string('password');
       $table->rememberToken();
       $table->timestamps();
   });
 }
```

I need to edit in register controller .How can insert data for user_level . For first user registeration ,it will be Null. But new user under him need to be level 1 and second generation need to be level 2. How can do it.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
   $referred_by = Cookie::get('referral');

   $user =  User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
                'affiliate_id' => str_random(10),
                'referred_by'   => $referred_by,
            ]);

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: you can fetch referral user by `referred_by` and then check that user `user_level` and then pay based on it

Comment: How can code it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user registration seems like multiple level system. I think its like something multiple user registration based on reference. So for this as you have already created a column named user_level.  when your new user create account directly in your website on that controller set your user level 1 by default. But after that when that newly created user send invitation to other you can send there with your invitation provider user level as get request. thus by following this request when new user will register then their user level will incremented by one.

Comment: what if the user registers without anyone's refer? is he given level 1?

Comment: $referred_by = Cookie::get('referral');  and $userlevel = $_GET['refered_by']

Comment: I use referral link and I will give user as level under owner of  referral link.If someone register by wihout referral link.He will be Null in referred_by